# not able to generate different id of html radio button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
 @for(int i = 0; i < item.Options.Count ; i++)
      {   
   <input id="RdOpt +@i"  type="radio" value="@item.Options" name="StudAns" />@item.Options[i]                 
          }
```

**id="RdOpt +(@i+1)"**

m not able to generate different id of radio button.i want to use htm control only.

can any one please help me with this syntax as i have search a lot on internet.

i want to generate different id of radio button like RdOpt1,RdOpt2..means till the loop

m not geeting error but id is not generating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
<input id="RdOpt@(i+1)"  type="radio" value="@item.Options" name="StudAns" />
```